# How to parse raw HTTP request (to get Soap XML from its content) with Python?

Tags: python, http, post, soap

I have raw http POST request with Soap message inside:

```
                POST / HTTP/1.1
                Host: localhost
                Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
                Content-Length: 431

                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
                    <soap12:Body>
                    </soap12:Body>
                </soap12:Envelope>
```

I would like use already implemented Python library to get XML content (SOAP message) from this raw data. And also would be nice to get HTTP request other content (Http version, Host, content-type ...) I tried to search it, but no success.

I know what I could simple use find in string like i.e. `"<?xml version="`
and it will indicate the beginning of XML message and after read to the end of the raw request will get me full soap message. But it's not very elegant solution.

Any ideas of available libraries or tools?

Comment: Could you please, clarify you task. Do you have this SOAP message in a text file on a local machine and you need to parse it? Or are you implementing a server that might receive such messages, parse tham and do somthing with it's content?

Comment: I have a server who is listening on TCP port. It receives this HTTP POST request with SOAP message inside. We could call it web service message.

Comment: One more question: what king of web server are use using? Is it just a socket? I'm asking because usually web-servers (Apache, nginx) process headers themselves and strip the payload from them.

Comment: It just a socket. I'm creating various types of servers using twisted framework. I'm already did manual parsing. Just searching for new lines in HTTP header and parsing content length from it and wait for length of bytes. So it's quite simple and maybe elegant solution.

Comment: You may use https://github.com/benoitc/http-parser/